# Starting multiple ffmpeg instances

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

New to linux and having problems.

I am trying to setup a system that will allow me to start multiple ffmpegs to convert live TV so I can archive certain programs.  The source is a few TV cards which means I can encode multiple streams at the same time. The PC is an i7 8 core.

I have tried to write a program that uses threads to start multiple ffmpegs and capture all the ffmpeg messages so I can watch the time elapsed, and when this hits a predetermined time stops the task and ffmpeg and then waits for the next scheduled recording, but I'm stuck on the capture of the ffmpeg output.

Comment: i7 8 cores? or i7 4 cores with hyperthreading?

Comment: what do you mean under "capture of the ffmpeg output"? writing encoded streams to file or something else?

Comment: I guess he means the standard output in the terminal that he wants to capture for monitoring purpose. If it's that you'll have to give us more details about the program. Which language ?

Comment: The ffmpeg chatter comes on `stderr`.  As Martin says, we would need to know what language you want to work in to provide further details.

Answer (score 0):

See [popen](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_popen.htm) function.